# TI BASIC remainder() domain error

Tags: ti-basic

In my TI BASIC program on TI 84 plus C, I have a line that says `remainder((A/X),2)`. This creates a domain error every time the program runs.  In the case of my tests, A/X is 4. `remainder(4,2)` works. `4->Z remainder(Z,2)` works. If I pause the program and display (A/X) immediately before the remainder line, the result is certainly 4. `(A/X)->Z remainder(Z,2)` does not work.
What could possibly be wrong with my code?

link to the code:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B07yHA0-EssLUjZOc0dxektwbUU

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B07yHA0-EssLSFlNcFNWZm0zNDQ

Comment: The code snippet works for me. A domain error occurs if the divisor or dividend is either negative or not an integer (for example 4.0001). Could you please post the complete code?

Comment: It would be useful to have it in text (not all of it though, it's quite long, just some relevant part) in [sourcecoder](https://www.cemetech.net/sc/) format

Comment: The program you've linked works for me (with some minor modifications), but the `remainder()` function isn't used at all in it. Are you sure that this is the correct program?

Comment: Apologies, I uploaded an old version. It should be fixed now. The relevant segment starts around "If S"

Comment: Which input values (function, bounds, ...) do you use to trigger the error?

Comment: 1, 2, 3, then select simpson from the menu

Comment: side note: I think you should be using `(A - L) / theta`, since you want to start counting from the left bound. You are only coincidentally getting `A / theta` as an integer since `L - 0` (1) is a multiple of `R - L` (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a valid substitution for `remainder()`.

```
2fPart(A/(2X))
```

This works because the general form, `KfPart(A/K)` takes the fractional part of A/K, which will be the same as `remainder(A,K)` if A is an integer. TI-BASIC doesn't always return an integer value. For example, `logBASE(16,2)` is ever so slightly less than 4. When we multiply by `K`, we change the range from being 0 to 1, to 0 to K.

Nothing is inherently wrong with your code, it is TI-BASIC that is *sometimes* wrong.